# Notificiones en tiempo real con php

Tags: php, html, css

Hola que tal buenos días amigos, alguien me podría guiar en el proceso de notificaciones para mi web en tiempo real.

No se que tan bien hecho este realizar una consulta con JavaScript cada  cierto tiempo, puede esto saturar la aplicación.

Comment: Te recomiendo mejor usar un servicio como Firebase o OneSignal dependiendo de tus necesidades. Tu pregunta es muy abierta, si quieres una mejor respuesta debes ser más especifico con lo que quieres lograr y los problemas que has tenido intentando lograrlo.

Comment: amigo muchas gracias por su respuesta "Gran sabiduría". Si claro tendré en cuenta tus criticas constructivas para la próxima muchas gracias.